# java RMI over the internet. host refuse connection

Tags: java, rmi

we are trying to get RMI working over the Internet. What we tried:

1. Port forwarding  (1099-1100) on Client and Serverside.
2. shut down firewall in windows and router
3. tried it with tunngle  (www.tunngle.net/)

our RMI Interface:

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface RMIInterface extends java.rmi.Remote    {
  public void helloWorld(int i) throws RemoteException;
}
```

our RMI Server Implementation:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class RMIServerTest extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RMIInterface {

    public RMIServerTest() throws RemoteException {
    }

    @Override
    public void helloWorld(int i) throws RemoteException {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
            }

            catch (RemoteException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                    Naming.rebind("Server", new RMIServerTest());
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

    }
}
```

and our Client:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;


public class RMIClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException,MalformedURLException {
    try {

       RMIInterface serverObject = (RMIInterface) Naming.lookup("//externalServerAdress/Server");
        serverObject.helloWorld(10);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }


  }
}
```

We're still getting this Error:

```
Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.13; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

192.168.0.13 is the local IP-adress of the Server behind his router. We connect on client with the external IP of the router. like "2.246.133.155"  = externalServerAdress.
So we have a connection. We connect over the external IP adress of the server (WAN IP) and error shows, it gets the local IP-adress of the server, but still refuse connection.

thx for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.13
```

That's not an Internet address. It is a private address that only exists behind your router. You need to use your *public* IP address, and arrange port forwarding via your router.

Comment: we connect on client with the router IP adress of the server network. we dont really know why we get here the local IP adress of the server behind his router. but it cant be magic, so connection exist.  (I edited orignial post to make it clearer)

Comment: In that case you need to read [item A.1 of the RMI FAQ](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain).

Comment: we did bind the external WAN IP with:  System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");but always get the same Error  (Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.13) its kinda strange :/

Comment: You need to set the property before creating any remote objects, including Registries.

Comment: was a problem with our routers firewall settings - worked instantly ,without any problems in our own subnetwork :)